# Error while getting debug certificate in command prompt

Tags: android, firebase, command-prompt, sha1

I get the following error while I try to get debug certificate in command prompt.

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both
> -exportcert and -list were specified

The program that I run is:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the command for windows. However, In the new documentation you can see that keytool will only accept 1 argument that is `-list`. For more details refer to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).

Exact code the you need should look like this. Just copy and paste the code in the console
`keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`